# Where date is bigger than in Rails 4 and Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to fire an active record query within my rails 4 app on this model:

```
Period(id: integer, from: date, to: date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

The query is supposed to give back all Periods that haven't ended it so the `:to`-date should be bigger than the current date:

```
    Period.where("to >?", Date.today)

And I am getting this error:

  irb(main):011:0> Period.all.where("from > ?", Date.today)
  Period Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "periods".* FROM "periods"  WHERE (from > '2015-11-24')
  Period Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "periods".* FROM "periods"  WHERE (from > '2015-11-24')
PG::SyntaxError: FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei "from"
LINE 1: SELECT "periods".* FROM "periods"  WHERE (from > '2015-11-24...
                                                  ^
: SELECT "periods".* FROM "periods"  WHERE (from > '2015-11-24')
PG::SyntaxError: FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei "from"
LINE 1: SELECT "periods".* FROM "periods"  WHERE (from > '2015-11-24...
                                                  ^
```

Since it says syntax error I assume that postgres is using a different syntax than sql but I wasn't able to find the right way online.

Would appreciate some help here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`from` is a SQL reserved word, so its hitting parsing errors.

You'll need to quote it:

`Period.where('"from" > ?', Date.today)`

In Postgres you double-quote `"` is how you escape reserved words, column names, etc.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my night :D

Comment: For **greater or equal than** is just simple as adding the corresponding symbol `>=` instead of just `>` or I need to do something else?

Comment: btw, no need to add `all`. Period.where is enough.